# How to update/regenerate CRUD code using OIL package in FuelPHP

Tags: fuelphp

I am new to FuelPHP ... I have generated curd code using the  following command `php oil generate scaffold/crud monkey name:string still_here:bool`
it generate migration files, views, controller, and model.. than I use the following command to create database tables `php oil refine migrate` everything is fine...

but what i need now is to update the table means i want to add more columns to the monkey table in database.... how and what is the reliable way to do this?? so that it will auto update the files as well

Comment: AFAIK There is no official way for updating a generated CRUD code. You need to add things manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in way of doing this. The only thing you can do is generating migrations or manually creating them and updating your models.

See how to generate migrations: http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/oil/generate.html#migrations